# Utilizar dos veces el mismo hook en react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Soy nuevo en `react`, así que es probable que esta pregunta no sea tan complicada.

Tengo un hook(UseFetch) que realiza peticiones fetch y retorna errores o alguna animacion de loading mientras se ejecuta

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

const useFetch = url => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    const [error, setError] = useState(null)
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

    useEffect( () => {    
        const fetchResource = async () => {
            try {
                let res = await fetch(url);
                let data = await res.json();

                setLoading(false)
                setData(data)
                //console.log(data)                        
            } catch (error) {
                setLoading(false)
                setError(error)
            }
        }
        fetchResource()
    }, [url])

    return { data, error, loading }
}

export default useFetch
```

Este hook lo utilizo en diferentes componentes y funciona bien, pero actualmente tengo un componente llamado `Inicio` en el cual necesito que realice dos peticiones dentro del mismo pero no encuentro la manera. Lo intente de la siguiente forma pero me marca un error de sintaxis en el `if (loadingCarrusel)`:

> Syntax error: Unexpected token

```
const Inicio = () => {
    const {data, error, loading} = useFetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/?_limit=5')
    const {dataCarrusel, errorCarrusel, loadingCarrusel} = useFetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/?_limit=5')

    if (loading)
        return <Loading />
    if (error)
        return <FatalError msg="Hubo un error al realizar la solicitud" />

    return <div className="row pb-3">
        <div className="col-3">
            <Fotos fotos={data} />
        </div>
        <div className="col-6">                
            { if (loadingCarrusel)
                return <Loading />
            if (errorCarrusel)
                return <FatalError msg="Hubo un error al realizar la solicitud" />
            }
            <Carrusel fotos={dataCarrusel} />
        </div>
    </div>
}

export default Inicio
```

Desde que hago el return dentro de otro return sé que está mal lo que hago pero no se como solucionar esto. La única solución que encuentro es crear un nuevo componente desde donde llamar al otro fetch pero quisiera saber si se puede dentro del mismo.

**UPDATE**

Ya estuve investigando y tiene que ver con algo llamado [renderizado condicional](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) pero aún así la segunda llamada me retorna `undefined` al hacer `console.log(dataCarrusel);`. Coloco el código actualizado

```
const Inicio = () => {
    const {data, error, loading} = useFetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/?_limit=5')
    const {dataCarrusel, errorCarrusel, loadingCarrusel} = useFetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/?_limit=10')
    console.log(dataCarrusel);

    if (loading)
        return <Loading />
    if (error)
        return <FatalError msg="Hubo un error al realizar la solicitud" />

    return <div className="row pb-3">
        <div className="col-3">
            <Fotos fotos={data} />
        </div>
        <div className="col-6">
            {
            loadingCarrusel &&
                <Loading /> 
            }
            {
            errorCarrusel &&
                <FatalError msg="Hubo un error al realizar la solicitud" />
            }
            { dataCarrusel &&
                <Carrusel fotos={dataCarrusel} />
            }
        </div>
        
    </div>
}

export default Inicio
```

Comment: Podrías agregar el error que recibes, `Syntax error: Unexpected token` no hace tanta referencia a el error que estas recibiendo

Comment: @Enzo es justo el error que aparece y señala la linea **if (loadingCarrusel):**. Solo indica cual  numero de linea es con exactitud pero no son más datos importantes

Comment: ¿Por qué no les pusiste los `{}` a los  `If` ni los `()` al tercer `return`?

Comment: @Desarrollos-Web-Urquiza si se omiten los `{}` con una simple identacion puede funcionar de igual manera el condicional, por otro lado, @Rene en tu hook estas retornando un objeto con tres propiedades, el primer hook va a funcionar por que obiamente estas destructurando las propiedas correctas, el segundo hook no va a funcionar por que estas extrayendo propiedades que en tu hook no exite, para que puedas obtener los datos que estas pidiendo puedes hacer uso de la palabra clave `as`, ejemplo `const {data as dataCarrusel, error as errorCarrusel , loading as loadingCarrusel} = useFetch(MyUrl)`

Comment: Esto debería lidiar con tu código, de igual manera si `as` no es de gran ayuda, puedes  nombrar a las propiedades de la siguiente manera `{data: dataCarrusel, error: errorCarrusel , loading: loadingCarrusel}`

Comment: @Enzo tienes razón, no recordaba la destructuracion por no estar familiarizado del todo con ecmascript, ya funciona. Una ultima consulta, sabes si esto de llamar varias veces el mismo hook es buena practica o es algo inusual?? Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: en mi opinión y en mi experiencia trataría de evitar siempre de tener varios hooks dentro de un componente ya que si uno de alguna forma cambia el componente vuelve hacer render, hay varias api's de react que te ayudan a lidear con esto como `useMemo` o tambien `memo`, pero si tu aplicación lo requiere, pues que mas, pero evitaría tener demasiados hooks dentro de un mismo componente

Comment: grcias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quiero agradecer a [Enzo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/147597/enzo) por la ayuda brindada para resolver este problema, el error era que estaba olvidando que las variables del segundo hook se estaban asignado por medio de destructuración y por lo tanto había un error. La solución fue modificar la linea:

```
const {dataCarrusel, errorCarrusel, loadingCarrusel} = useFetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/?_limit=10')
```

por

```
const {data as dataCarrusel, error as errorCarrusel, loading as loadingCarrusel} = useFetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/?_limit=10')
```